# How to disable auto format HTML in VScode Jupyter?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I am using VScode to edit a Jupyter notebook file.
The Python interactive window does not output what I expected.
It seems that VScode tries to display the string as a HTML code, but that is wrong. 
How can I disable this feature?

https://wx2.sinaimg.cn/mw690/58daa6d3gy1fyva4tjpb6j20oi0iadgz.jpg

I've tried many ways to disable this feature, but I cannot find anything useful.

My code:

```
a = 6
b = type(a)
print(b)
print("<222>")
print("<class 222>")
```

What I expected:

```
<class 'int'>
<222>
<class 222>
```

What the interactive window shows:

```
<222>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't turn it off. Please make a feature request/bug report at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.